# Cracked wall, is it serious?

Tags: walls, exterior

I am in the process of purchasing a home and this was reported in the inspection report. The side of the house showed long cracked lines of the wall "with deformation". Would anyone be able to tell if this is serious? The seller does not want to fix it on their own, and agree to give us $2,000 (which I think is not enough to cover the cost to repair this).

I was wondering about how much would this cost from a professional?

[image: Cracked wall with deformation]

[image]

Comment: The upper picture looks like a crappy job of applying the next level up of an EIFS system where they stopped one day and started the next. The lower picture is another story. What it takes to bulge a wall like that is a pressure from the inside pushing out, or something making the wall get shorter somehow and the finish on the outside has to make accommodations for a wall that is no longer as tall as it used to be, making the wall buckle. What does the wall look like around the corner where the buckle is? Is there a vertical separation there? or just another somewhat horizontal line?

Comment: Your best bet is to actually get two or three professionals to come give you quotes. Most do it for free, but even if they charge a small fee, it's still worth knowing if you're going to be hit with thousands in repairs.

Comment: The bulge may be caused by water getting behind the plaster... oh.. its right by a drain pipe too... ond judging by all the mould there it must get wet pretty often, on the outside. Only way to find out.. take off the plaster. If the bricks are cracked / bulging you have serious problems. We cant judge this superficially. 2000USD , thats a figure taken out of their butts so to speak. If the bricks are cracking, then what? Insurance wont cover that.. it will be more like 50-100k bill! Get a pro in, look under the plaster, if the seller declines, move on, you wont regret it.

Answer (score 1):

Just from the pictures it looks like a bad install.  The cracks look like they are rolled.  They aren't on any parts of the structure where there are two joints meeting or any sort of weak point.  They are basically right in the middle of a wood framed exterior.

[Remember this advice is just based on me looking at a couple pictures and from what you said about inspection.  I am thinking that your inspector really looked hard on the other side of these cracks and found nothing.  They don't seem structural (but could be).  So I am really relying on your inspector doing a thorough job.]

How would I approach this?  First @Jack's comments are correct.  It looks like EIFS.  So I would get a couple of EIFS/Stucco installers out to get quotes on what they think is wrong and how to correct.  I am going to guess that there were installation steps or materials skipped.  A total guess would be that they left no expansion gaps for the insulation and that the insulation expanded and pushed out the finish layer.

If the installers say something similar and quote you something now you have a dilemma.  This doesn't seem to be a huge thing.  But given they made a mistake here, it was probably made everywhere.  This is probably the first issue since it is the biggest continuous exterior wall.

So I would go into this with the thinking that if it is an install issue then you might have more.  I would also figure out the age of the install.  If it is less than 5 years old I would think this waves can pop up everywhere.  If it is 10-15 years old I would be less concerned.  But really it looks to me to be a cosmetic issue and if you are the type of person that doesn't care about that as much, it really isn't a big deal.  Really this is why stucco and EIFS has more issues in temperate climates and is found more in the far south (or Spain and France).